# Impala - Let Impala pick its own memory limit

Tags: cloudera, impala, cloudera-manager

I have Cloudera Express 5.3.2 installed on a cluster. I would like to use it for Impala querying.

I want to let Impala set the limit depending on the cluster's capacity. In the Impala configuration, in cloudera manager, it's written to "leave it blank to let Impala pick its own limit".  However I can't leave the field blank because the web interface tells me that "this field is required".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhyNm.png

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Impala cannot set its own memory limit. You don't have to set a memory limit (use -1), but your queries will perform poorly if you run out of physical memory and the OS is forced to swap. If you're only using Impala on this cluster (i.e. not Hive, MapReduce, Spark, etc.), you can set this to most of the physical memory; we typically recommend 80%. If you do need to share resources with other systems, you should look at the [resource management options available in CDH](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/admin_rm.html).

Comment: Umm, sorry for this shameless misuse of comment section. But can you please help me with these,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125455/using-hive-udf-in-impala-gives-erroneous-results-in-impala-1-2-4

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127419/native-impala-udf-cpp-randomly-gives-result-as-null-for-same-inputs-in-the-sam