# Using Hive UDF in Impala gives erroneous results in Impala 1.2.4

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, impala, udf

I have two Hive UDFs in Java which work 
perfectly well in Hive.

Both functions are complimentary to each other.

```
String myUDF(BigInt)
BigInt myUDFReverso(String)
```

`myUDF("myInput")` gives some output which 
when `myUDFReverso(myUDF("myInput"))` 
should give back `myInput`

This works in Hive but when I try to use 
it in Impala (version 1.2.4) it gives expected
answer for `myUDF(BigInt)` (the answer printed is correct)
but the answer when passed to `myUDFReverso(String)` doesn't give 
back original answer).

I have noticed that `length(myUDF("myInput"))` in Impala 1.2.4
is wrong. It is +1 for every row. And again 
it is correct in case of Hive and also Impala (version 2.1)

So, I assume there is some extra(special) character being appended
at the end of the output of `myUDF` in Impala 1.2.4 (Precisely at the end
of the `Text` datatype returned from the UDF function).

I have built a similar UDF for Impala 1.2.4 in Cpp and it works correctly.

All these issues are resolved in Impala 2.1 but I cannot
upgrade my cluster to it.

So how do I work around this bug?

Reference: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/v1/v1-2-4/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_udf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [IMPALA-1134](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1134) which was fixed in Impala 2.1. The issue is that the returned value is copied in the wrong way such that some extra memory may be returned at the end of your string. Previously we were using [getBytes()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#getBytes()) which says only the data up to `getLength()` is valid. I think it could be possible to try to encode the real length in the output and then in your reversal function, take the real length and only use the valid portion. However, this seems pretty tricky. I'd highly recommend finding a way to upgrade to the latest version of Impala as there are many bug fixes since 1.4.